# IF ELSE VBA not working

Tags: excel, vba

Been working on this code and still can't get it to work. I've tried to piece it together through searching and copying similar codes but been unsuccessful at duplicating the solutions given.

I have Worksheet A and Worksheet B. I have table A on Worksheet A and table B on Worksheet B. I want to autofilter Table A and copy the results ("Quick Status" column="closed") (excluding header info) to bottom of table B.

If that criteria is met ("Quick Status" column ="closed"), it copies those rows with "closed" as the criteria in the "Quick Status" column and pastes it over on the other sheet and then deletes the data from Table A. Works as intended.

However if I have a day where I did not close any files, autofilter would return no results. That is when the issue occurs.
When I am stepping thru it in the debugger - it continues thru the "IF" portion and gets stuck at

```
   Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).SpecialCells   (xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
```

Not sure why it doesn't stop at the IF portion and move down to Else. The If portion should detect that the results are less then 1 so it should clear the filters and then populate a msg box informing the user that they did not close any files that day.

"PendA" is name of Table A.
"Quick Status" is name of Column in Table A that I am searching for the criteria "Closed".
Table A starts on B14. And ends on Column L.

```
Sub MoveC()
'
' MoveC Macro


Dim rng As Range, res As Variant, lrow As Long


Set rng = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("PendA").AutoFilter.Range.Rows(1)
res = Application.Match("Quick Status", rng, 0)
rng.AutoFilter Field:=res, Criteria1:="Closed"

lrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, res).End(xlUp).Row + 1



If ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, res), Cells(lrow, res)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count > 1 Then
    Range("B15:L15").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy


    Sheets("Closed").Select
    Range("A2000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False


    Sheets("Pending").Select
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("PendA").DataBodyRange.Rows.Delete
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("PendA").Range.AutoFilter Field:=8


Else

    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("PendA").Range.AutoFilter Field:=8

    MsgBox "No Closures found. Should have taken a PTO today."

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Remove the `+ 1` from `lrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, res).End(xlUp).Row + 1` and see if it works. If not, I have another method because using `SpecialCells` to test can be tricky if you don't get logic *just right*. And why do you work with `ListObject` in beginning of code and then `Ranges` in the middle. If you stick with `ListObject` object model you're code would be easier to read, maintain.

Comment: @scott Holtzman - I tried removing the +1 from lrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, res).End(xlUp).Row + 1   but still same issue.  As to why I switched between methods, I couldn't figure out how to paste the copied data into the bottom of Table B especially when I was pasting multiple rows and use Paste Special Values. Every time I tried to code it, I would run into errors or it would add a blank row at the bottom of table B and not paste any data. This was the only I could get it work properly.   As you can probably gather - I am new to VBA.

Comment: Change `ActiveSheet` to explicitly state the worksheet you want to work with in all instances` ... like `Worksheets("SheetA")` and / or `Worksheets("SheetB")`. The `ActiveSheet` may not be what you think it is. If this doesn't solve issue, I will write out an answer that will most likely work.

Comment: I did as you suggested but still no cigar. Thanks for your help by the way.

Comment: Do you know how to use the debugger to set a breakpoint and look at the evaluated expression?

Comment: @theMayer I do not but I will look into breakpoints in VBA after I try Scott's suggestion.

Comment: I would recommend learning how to use the debugger *before* trying the suggestion. Refactoring your code is not going to help you fix the next problem that comes along - and wouldn't you like three days of your life back? http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Overall there is a better way to structure your code for accuracy, maintainability and ease of reading.

Try the below. It checks for instances of "Closed" in the column *before* the filter.

```
Sub MoveC()

    Dim PendATbl as ListObject
    Set PendATbl = Worksheets("A").ListObjects("PendA") 'change as needed

    With PendATbl

        If Not .ListColumns("Quick Status").DataBodyRange.Find("Closed", lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then

            .ListColumns("Quick Status").Range.AutoFilter 1, "Closed"
            .DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

             Sheets("Closed").Range("A2000").End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

            .DataBodyRange.Rows.Delete

        Else

           .Range.AutoFilter Field:=8
            MsgBox "No Closures found. Should have taken a PTO today."

        End If 

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Getting a "syntax error" at the following line       If Not .ListColumns("Quick Status").DataBodyRange.Find("Closed", lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing

Comment: @Den - That pesky `Then` word, gets me everytime! Try now.

Comment: Odd now it stopped earlier in the macro - it stopped at this line Set PendATbl = Worksheets("A").ListObjects("PendA") .   It gave a subscript out of range error

Comment: @Den - make sure Worksheet and Table name match to yours.

Comment: "Give a man a fish, and you feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish, and you feed him for a lifetime"

Comment: Oops can't believe I missed that. Thanks code works perfectly.   @theMayer - I'll go and do some more learning.