# Compile Error: For Without Next | Moving row to separate worksheet based on string values in column

Tags: vba, excel

Issue:

- Compile error: 
  For without Next

Objective:

- If Column L in tblData on Sheet1 equals any of the values named in the strPhase then copy the entire row. Then take the copied row and add this to  tblClosed on Sheet2. Then delete the original row from Sheet 1. In essence it is moving the row to sheet2.

Edited for Clarification 4:00 PM 11/2

```
Sub closedsheet()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim datasheet As Worksheet 'where is the data copied from
    Dim closedsheet As Worksheet 'where is the data pasted to
    Dim strPhase() As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim intPhaseMax As Integer
    Dim lngLstRow As Long
    Dim rngCell As Range
    Dim finalrow As Integer
    Dim lr As Long 'row counter
    Dim Looper As Integer

    intPhaseMax = 6
    ReDim strPhase(1 To intPhaseMax)

    strPhase(1) = "LOST"
    strPhase(2) = "BAD"
    strPhase(3) = "UNINTERESTED"
    strPhase(4) = "UNRELATED"
    strPhase(5) = "UNDECIDED"
    strPhase(6) = "BUDGET"

    'set variables
    Set datasheet = Sheet1
    Set closedsheet = Sheet2

lr = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For Looper = LBound(strPhase) To UBound(strPhase)

    For i = lr To 6 Step -1
    If Not Sheet1.Range("L8:L300" & lngLstRow).Find(strPhase(Looper), lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then
        Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 20)).Copy
        Sheet2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(3)(2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 20)).Delete
    End If
Next

Sheet2.columns.AutoFit
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Sheet2.Select
Sheet2.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("A9:U" & lr), , xlYes).Name = 
"tblClosed"

End Sub
```

[image: Sheet 1 Pipeline_Input]
[image: Sheet 2 Closed_Sheet]

Comment: 1) The text you wrote and the code you gave are not identical at all. Your code contains arrays of different values and your text says only find "Closed". 2) This question is **almost identical** to one I just answered yesterday and will work in this instance.

Comment: "`Dim lngLstRoaw As Long`" Roaw? Is that intentional? You also use `lngLstRow` later in your code, but where do you even give a value to that variable??? You need `Option Explicit` at the top of your subroutine.

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47062643/if-else-vba-not-working/47063360#47063360) I answered yesterday.

Comment: I'm very new to VBA so i've been trying to piece together statements that I thought would work. I have been searching through many different posts and i'm sure some of these statements are completely unrelated but this is as far as I have got to. @dwirony the Roaw is not intentional and I will change that.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman
1) I meant that i need to search for each of the strings and they are considered closed terms rather than won or open. I need to search the column for each of those string possibilities and if it matches any of them, to trigger the copy. How would it work when i need to search multiple values?

Comment: Can you just search for not equal `Won` or `Open`? This will be easier.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman unfortunately no, because we need to be doing analytics on each of the types of lost opportunities. Is there a way to just write:
If column L contains ("Array" with the noted words) complete the action?

Answer (score 0):

This answer addresses the question in your last comment.

```
Dim Looper as Integer

For Looper = Lbound(strPhase) to Ubound(strPhase)

    If Not Range("L8:L" & lngLstRow).Find(strPhase(Looper),lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then 

        'copy paste code .... 

    End If

Next
```

Comment: Thank you that helps a lot as I did know of looper action. I really appreciate this help as I feel so helpless trying to get this to work :(

Would I start your snippet as a replacement for :
    For Each rngCell In Range("L8:L" & lngLstRow)
            For i = lr To 6 Step -1
                If strPhase(i) = rngCell.Value Then

? @scottholtzman

Comment: @Kobetron - Yes. You can replace that with my snippet.

Comment: Definitely getting close as the debug is going better but i am now getting the following error:
Run-time error '1004':  <br/>
Method 'Range' of object'_Global' failed  <br/>
for the line  <br/>
If Not Range("L8:L" & lngLstRow).Find........

Comment: I've reworded the question and shown my exact error. Any thoughts?

Comment: If you have a different question as a result of incorporating an answer, that should **really** be made into a **new** question. The original question should be left in tact so it does not confuse new users. That said, the error you get now is a result of not closing the `For i = lr To 6 Step -1` block with `Next`.

Comment: Confirmed and will make sure to do this in the future. I am no longer getting errors but the code does not do anything. No data is transferred to sheet 2, should I start a new question in this instance?

Comment: @Kobetron - Perhaps. Make sure the sheet object names you are using are  correct. i.e. - Sheet1 is object name for sheet you think it is.